# Which Angular 1.5 component binding type is more expensive? '=' or '<'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-component, angular-components

If I have a component and I have bound some variables to it - ignoring use cases for uni and bidirectional flow - which is more computationally expensive? `=` or `<`?

I initially though `<` would be cheaper as we don't need to propagate changes upwards, however considering the copy needed surely `=` would be beneficial most times since it'll just pass the reference through?

Or is it just related to the need for `$onChanges`?

Comment: '=' is cheaper, '<' is more transparent

Comment: So would you say if you know what you're doing, use '='?

Comment: _"considering the copy needed"_ Which copy?

Comment: When using <, I presume Angular copies the object as apposed to passing through the reference to the parents object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. '=' passes link, of course it is cheapest and simplest way. (In i.e. Java you always pass link.)
2. The problem is that you can not make this object or some its properties unmodifiable, you can not create interface or smth. Imagine hierarchy: `<component-a object="object"><component-b object="object"><component-c object="object">`

   Now you want to understand wtf is going here - who is setting or using what property - and you simply can not do it.
3. What I feel now:
   -for simple objects use '<', can use onChanges, looks nice.
   -for big, complicated objects use '=' (of course, do not pass functions within it)

Comment: Interesting. FYI you can achieve unmodifiable in es6 using const and even interfaces with typescript!

Comment: The only difference between `=` and `<` is that `<` does not propagate changes upwards.

Comment: wrong: http://plnkr.co/edit/vsFh3icprGZlxrJomfmS?p=preview as i said onChanges will not trigger for '=' binding

Answer (score 3):

In my mind, storage is cheaper than processing power, so the copy of the object is cheaper than another watch for object properties, every digest cycle.

Comment: But would it be another watch? isn't it true that each case would be watching a reference but in different scopes? (and i think  changing a deep property would still be reflected in the parent, but only in = would it be detected)